# How to get rows between a value until the value appears again

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I need to separate the rows between when Level is 1 until it is 1 again. These groups of rows will be separate dfs and grouped by their part name at level 1. But I will take care of that later. For now, I can't seem to figure out how to get all the rows between the systems as the amount of levels in a system are inconsistent.

My current work in progress is getting all the indexes where level is 1, then retrieving the rows in between. Is is very time consuming as some dfs will have about 50 systems.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB","AAB"] ,'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2],'Part':["Upper System","Upper 2 System","Upper 2 stock","Upper System","Middle","Limits System", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})


    Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper System
1   A          1    Upper 2 System
2   A          2    Upper 2 stock
3   ABC        1    Upper System
4   ABC        3    Middle
5   AAB        1    Limits System
6   AAB        4    Deck
7   AAB        2    Ceiling
```

I need the dfs to look like something like these

```
    Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper

    Name    Level   Part
0   A          1    Upper 2 System
1   A          2    Upper 2 stock

    Name    Level   Part
0   ABC        1    Upper System
1   ABC        3    Middle

    Name    Level   Part
0   AAB        1    Limits System
1   AAB        4    Deck
2   AAB        2    Ceiling
```

Comment: what if the first element has `Level != 1` ? What if the last in 1?

Comment: Can you explain your question? The Level indicates its location in a hierarchy from 1-nth. System is at the highest position so it will always be level one. If the original df had the parts out of order, then I dont think we could do anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: added advice from Ruggero Turra's comment

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB","AAB"] ,'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2],'Part':["Upper System","Upper 2 System","Upper 2 stock","Upper System","Middle","Limits System", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})

split=[v.reset_index() for k, v in df.groupby((df['Level']==1).cumsum())]

for d in split.values():
    print(d,"\n")

>>>    index Name  Level          Part
>>> 0      0    A      1  Upper System 

>>>    index Name  Level            Part
>>> 0      1    A      1  Upper 2 System
>>> 1      2    A      2   Upper 2 stock

>>>    index Name  Level          Part
>>> 0      3  ABC      1  Upper System
>>> 1      4  ABC      3        Middle 

>>>    index Name  Level           Part
>>> 0      5  AAB      1  Limits System
>>> 1      6  AAB      4           Deck
>>> 2      7  AAB      2        Ceiling
```

How does it works:
1 finds the rows where Level is 1, equivalent to:

```
df["=1"]=1*(df["Level"]==1)
```

Then calculates the cummulative sum, equivalent to:

```
df["Cummmulative sum"]=df["=1"].cumsum()
```

Now, the column "Cummulative sum" has an unique identifier for each group:

```
Name  Level            Part  =1  Cummmulative sum
0    A      1    Upper System   1                 1
1    A      1  Upper 2 System   1                 2
2    A      2   Upper 2 stock   0                 2
3  ABC      1    Upper System   1                 3
4  ABC      3          Middle   0                 3
5  AAB      1   Limits System   1                 4
6  AAB      4            Deck   0                 4
7  AAB      2         Ceiling   0                 4
```

Comment: this `split=dict(tuple(df.groupby((df['Level']==1).cumsum())))` can be simplified as `[v for k, v in df.groupby((df['Level']==1).cumsum())]`

Comment: you need to `reset_index`

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB","AAB"] ,'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2],'Part':["Upper System","Upper 2 System","Upper 2 stock","Upper System","Middle","Limits System", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})

from itertools import pairwise
import numpy as np

iloc_split = np.nonzero((df.Level.iloc[1:] == 1).values)[0] + 1
iloc_split = [None] + list(iloc_split) + [None]  # fix the boundaries

# do the actual split
dfs = [df.iloc[start:stop].reset_index(drop=True) for start, stop in pairwise(iloc_split)]

for r in dfs:
    print(r)
```

You have to be careful about the first and last block, depending on exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is so cool! Thank you for showing me itertools. Would using pandas to do the numpy stuff work well too? For example, to find the indexes, df[df["Level"]==1].index.to_list(). Also, I'm new to python, could you explain the list comprehension? I understand what its doing for the most part. Lastly, What do you mean first and last?

Comment: in your case (where the index is `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`) yes. In general no.

Comment: How come you don't start from index 0 as its the first time level = 1? Also, could you turn the list comprehension into a normal for loop? I'm still learning python and it would help me better understand. Thank you for all the work you put into this!

Comment: The first item is always an edge, so I am not checking if the first item is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a group to the rows you want to group. As shown below, note you should use `itertuples` for faster dataframe loop, and update the `group` column once you have the final `group_values` list. Drop the `group` column if you don't need it after.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["A","A","A","ABC","ABC","AAB","AAB","AAB"] ,'Level': [1,1,2,1,3,1,4,2],'Part':["Upper System","Upper 2 System","Upper 2 stock","Upper System","Middle","Limits System", "Deck", "Ceiling"]})

group = 0
group_values = []
for df_tuple in df.itertuples(index=None, name=None):
    level = df_tuple[1]
    if level == 1:
        group += 1
    group_values.append(group)

df['group'] = group_values

for _, df_group in df.groupby('group'):
    print(df_group.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Easy and straight forward, instead of using some complex `groupby's` and/or `slicing`

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159661/2095411 is a better approach. Use that,

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that code for me. It was a cool approach and I learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_abc = df.groupby("NAME").get_group("ABC").reset_index()
df_aab = df.groupby("NAME").get_group("AAB").reset_index()
df_a = df.groupby("NAME").get_group("A").reset_index()

# Slicing the 'A' group
df_a0 = df_a.loc[0, :]
df_a12 = df_a.loc[ 1:2, :].reset_index()
```